KDTree buildBalancedTree infinite recursion issue
I tried to speed up my KD tree by implementing balancing and bounding boxes, but now it can't even build the tree, and I don't understand why.
Input Example
Here's how I provide the input:
n and dim = {3, 2} points: {0, 0} {3, 3} {3, 0}

Issue
When I attempt to build the tree, the function seems to go into infinite recursion, and the program hangs. I suspect the problem lies in my buildBalancedTree function.
Code
Here's the implementation of the buildBalancedTree function:
std::unique_ptr<KDTree::Node> KDTree::buildBalancedTree(
std::vector<Point>& points, 
int depth,
std::vector<long double> min_bound, 
std::vector<long double> max_bound) {

if (points.empty()) {
    return nullptr;
}

int axis = depth % points[0].point.size();

std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), [axis](const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    return a.point[axis] < b.point[axis];
});

size_t medianIndex = points.size() / 2;
Point medianPoint = points[medianIndex];

// Update bounds for left and right subtrees
std::vector<long double> left_max = max_bound;
left_max[axis] = medianPoint.point[axis];

std::vector<long double> right_min = min_bound;
right_min[axis] = medianPoint.point[axis];

auto node = std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(medianPoint), min_bound, max_bound);

node->left = buildBalancedTree(
    points, depth + 1, min_bound, left_max
);
node->right = buildBalancedTree(
    points, depth + 1, right_min, max_bound
);

return node;
}

My Thoughts
I believe the infinite recursion happens because I am passing the same points vector to both the left and right subtree builds. However, I am not sure how to correctly partition the points vector for the subtrees.
How can I fix this issue? If necessary, I can provide the full code of my program.

You only return from the function if points is empty. But you never remove any elements from points so it will never become empty, thus you have infinite recursion. What is your "base case" (when the recursion should end)? Is it really when points is empty? Should elements of points be removed? If not, then the base case needs to be something else. Alternatively, you need to make a copy of points with at least one element less than points, and use it in the recursive calls. Thus satisfying the base case of points becoming empty.

Have you ever implemented quicksort?

BTW: You don't need to run a full sort. std::nth_element(start, median, end) is sufficient (algorithm also known as quickselect)
